# .htaccess regex for redirectin specific url-endings

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

ATM we are investigating a bug in our webapp which produces duplicated urls for specific content. The duplicated urls get a suffix `-X` where X is an integer.

The right urls look like this:

```
http://www.foo.bar/entity/some-special-name
```

The duplicates look like this:

```
http://www.foo.bar/entity/some-special-name-1
```

Till we found the bug, we urgently need a workaround based on mod_rewrite which redirects the duplicate-urls to the originals. Has someone an idea, how I can achieve this kind of redirect? How would a regex look like? The redirect should only fire for urls in the `/entity/` subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this redirect rule in your site root .htaccess to remove invalid URLs:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)-\d+/?$ /$1
```

If you just want to fix `/entity/` URLs then use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/entity/.+)-\d+/?$ /$1
```

Comment: but this would be site-wide then? only in a specific subdirectory "entity" would be "RedirectMatch 301 ^/entity/(.+)-\d+/?$ /$1 then?

Comment: This will work for all the URLs across your website unless you have another .htaccess in sub-directories

Comment: as the urls are created by the cms we don't have "real" subdirectories. entity is just a route…

Comment: In that case this rule will work for `/entity/` URLs as well, just make sure this rule is very first line in your .htaccess

Comment: okay. it should work JUST in /entity/. so the rule from my first comment is appropriate?

Comment: If you just want to fix `/entity/` URLs then use `RedirectMatch 301 ^(/entity/.+)-\d+/?$ /$1`